# Copy next word line from sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i got code to find all rows that contain specific words then send it to another sheet and it works fine but i faced one issue that i want to copy the next row of found word then paste it in next column in next sheet.

code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForString()

    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant, fnd As Range, cpy As Range, addr As String

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    'populate the array for the outer loop
    arr = Array("Water", "Fighter", "Demon")

    With Worksheets("Data")

        'outer loop through the array
        For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'locate first instance
            Set fnd = .Columns("A").Find(what:=arr(a), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
               'record address of first find
                addr = fnd.Address
                'seed the cpy range object
                If cpy Is Nothing Then Set cpy = fnd.EntireRow
                Do
                    'build union
                    Set cpy = Union(cpy, fnd.EntireRow)

                    'look for another
                    Set fnd = .Columns("A").FindNext(after:=fnd)

                'keep finding new matches until it loops back to the first
                Loop Until fnd.Address = addr
            End If
        Next a

    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet19")
        'one stop copy & paste operation
        cpy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    Debug.Print Now & " " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

here is picture example

[image: Example]

i tried to use .Copy .Offset(1) but it wouldn't work, so i tried to ask here may someone got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding and pasting the data in one line, break it into two so that you can copy the offset and paste to the offset.

```vb
With Worksheets("sheet19")
    Dim dst As Range
    Set dst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

cpy.Copy Destination:=dst
cpy.Offset(1) Destination:=dst.Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you man, it's copying the offset(1) line, but i got little issue, that it's not paste it in next column offset(0, 1) for some reasons but i tried to copy it in same column offset(1, 0) and it's working, do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Oh, i had EntireRow in scripts, i have to remove it so i can move any data to any column, thank you it's all fixed now
special thanks to you really for this help.